# RecycleView with Viewpager not scrolling left and right while RecycleView in amiddle of scrolling

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

Even if i want to scroll left and right i need to be very precise with that cause if i move my finder a little bit up or down it will scroll the RecycleView (up/down) instead of the viewPager (Left/Right).

Anyone knows that issue i am really lost with it?
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you got to scroll event one for viewpager and the other for recycle view

and android can't tell the difference between both of them here are some steps you can use

- you can implement setOnPageChangeListener in your view pager

and then in onPageScrolled you can call

```
mPager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

so that you can handle touch events yourself

you can also call `recycleView.setEnabled(false);`

and then in `onPageScrollStateChanged`

```
if(state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
            recycleView.setEnabled(true);
```

it's not a pretty solution but it's just a work around so that you got one touch event while scrolling in view pager

I created an example below it's not the best still a little tricky but it's better than not doing anything

https://github.com/ahmed-basyouni/TestViewPagerRecycleView/tree/master

Comment: Also tried :  vpPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                setRecycleViewVisible(false);
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        setRecycleViewVisible(true);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });